# Movie where a professor opens a portal to hell

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv, horror

In this movie, a professor or maybe a scientist of some kind creates a device that opens a portal to hell. This ends up sending the main characters there. In hell, one of them is infested with parasites of some kind. Maybe they are giant worms? I don't quite remember. I think, during the course of the movie, the professor is trying to figure out how to teleport the characters out of hell, but I'm not sure about that part.

Another part that I remember is that two of the characters try to get out of hell by paying Charon to take them back to Earth. One of the characters finds a gold coin that can be used to that end. He tries to pay Charon using a gold-plated pocket watch. When he tries to get the coin to pay for another character's return trip, he realizes that his pocket has a hole in it, and that the coin fell out. Charon then says that he will only ferry one of them across. The two characters end up beheading Charon and taking his boat across Styx. However, Charon comes back as a flying beast and tries to stop them. The two characters end up successfully crossing the river Styx. One of them wakes up in the real world in the middle of Russia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty sure this is ***[They Found Hell](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5113926/)*** (2015).

> A group of college students are trapped in hell after a teleportation experiment goes awry, and the inhabitants are determined to devour their souls.

[This review](https://unobtainium13.com/2015/10/18/tsls-the-daily-horror-grindhouse-they-found-hell-dir-by-nick-lyon/) offers a decent summary of the plot.

> They Found Hell, which premiered last night on the SyFy channel, deserves a lot of credit.  In the tradition of the best grindhouse films (and, make no mistake, this was definitely a grindhouse film even if it was made for TV), They Found Hell delivers exactly what it promises.  The title tells us that “they” will find Hell and that’s exactly what happens.
>
> **“They” refers to a group of college students who, through some questionable use of science, manage to not only open up a portal into Hell but get sucked into it as well.  One student does manage to avoid getting sucked into the portal but he turns out to be pretty ineffective.  When he goes to the local crazy professor (James Sobol Kelly), he tells him what has happened, and then suggests maybe calling the police.  (I assume so that the police could read Hell its rights?)  The professor responds by tying the student up.  The professor has a plan of his own.**
>
> As for the students actually went down the portal … well, they’re in Hell.  One student insists that there’s no such thing as Hell and therefore, this must all be a dream.  Of course, he’s the first to die.  This, of course, leads to an interesting theological question: if an atheist dies in Hell, does he just come back to life?  I mean, he’s already in Hell.  What else can be done to him?
>
> Anyway, the remaining students soon find themselves split up and each exploring a different section of Hell.  And this is really where the movie triumphed because this was a very convincing and very memorable Hell.  One student found himself in a desolate forest and ended up getting attacked by a bunch of vines.  Another found herself wandering through the hallways of what appeared to be the ruins of a Tuscan castle.  Another student found himself in a burning city while two others found themselves chained to a wall while a pendulum swung back and forth.  (I assume they were in the Edgar Allan Poe Wing of Hell.)  It was all surprisingly well-done and quite creepy.
>
> At first, it seemed that Hell was nearly deserted and I guess we should be happy about that.  (I mean, humanity must be doing something right if there’s hardly anyone on the streets of Hell.)  But, as we quickly learn, the students are not alone.  There are lizard creatures that jump through windows.  There are snarling dogs that eat men who have been tied to the trees in a dark forest.  And, of course, there’s the succubus…
>
> **And then there’s Charon, the boatman.  In Greek mythology, Charon is the ferryman who takes souls across the River Styx.  Of course, he’ll only take you if you can pay the toll.  Charon’s always been one of my favorite mythological characters so I was definitely excited when he made an appearance here, looking all spooky and ghastly.**